# Passing Custom User Fields to WooCommerce Order Metadata

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields, user-data

I'm working on setting up an Woo site that will be integrated with a Sage X3 ERP system. We will be pushing new orders through to Sage. Now I am looking to add a custom ID field for each customer and I was able to accomplish that with the ACF plugin. Now I just need to find a way to push that ID through to the order metadata so that Sage can correctly identify the customer.

[image]

What would be the best way to accomplish that? The name of the of the field is "Sage X3 Customer ID" with the key being "sagecustomerid". Any help would be appreciated.

---

**Edit:**

I feel like I'm getting close, as I see the 'sagecustomerid' in the order meta now based on this code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 10, 2 ); 
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) { 
    $order->update_meta_data( 'sagecustomerid', '$value', $meta_id = 2746 ); 
}
```

How can I get the value from db table posts ID 2746?

I can't seem to get it to work.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Hey sorry about that, I'm relatively new to this side of things. I was able to find the field in the "wp_posts" database table (ID 2670). And yes, this is custom user field. This is only on the admin side of things, as I don't need the customer to see this information. What other information would be needed? Thank you.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec Ok yes, I just checked and there indeed is a "sagecustomerid" meta_key in the wp_usermeta table. Is it automatically being pushed through in that case? Or do I still need to add custom code? Thanks for your help.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I'm looking in /wp-json/wc/v3/orders as that is where the bridge will be made and I don't see the "sagecustomerid" anywhere. That's essentially where I'm looking to place this.

Comment: @LoicTheAztec But I did find it under /wp-json/wc/v3/customers/. Is that fine?

Comment: @LoicTheAztec I feel like I'm getting close, as I see the 'sagecustomerid' in the order meta now based on this code: </br>add_action('woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 10, 3);
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) {
    $order->update_meta_data( 'sagecustomer', '$value', $meta_id = 2746 );
} How can I get the value from db table wp_posts ID 2746? I can't seem to get it to work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the `meta ID` in your function, so in your function code you will have:

```
$order->update_meta_data( 'sagecustomer', $some_value );
```

> But you need to get `$some_value` from somewhere…

This is about post meta data, but not post data, so the related database table is **`wp_postmeta`** for orders…

If the data  you need come from user meta data, the code will be a bit different, like:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_create_order', 'before_checkout_create_order', 10, 2 ); 
function before_checkout_create_order( $order, $data ) { 
    if ( $value = get_user_meta( $order->get_user_id(), 'sagecustomerid', true ) ) {
        $order->update_meta_data( 'sagecustomer', $value ); 
    } 
}
```

Once done you will be able to get 'sagecustomer' meta value from:

- The `WC_Order` Object using: **`$value = $order->get_meta('sagecustomer');`**
- The order ID ($order_id) using: **`$value = get_post_meta($order_id, 'sagecustomer', true);`**

Comment: If the data I need is in the wp_usermeta table, does that affect how the code is structured? I can't seem to pull the value correctly.

Comment: You just made my day! This solved my dilemma. Seriously, thank you so much. Cheers.